# What is use of _pre() method in codginiter (CI)

Tags: php, codeigniter

What is use of `_pre()` method in codginiter (CI):

```
 <?php 
      $x = array('hello', 'ram', 'shyam');
     _pre($x);    
     die;
 ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a shorthand to output your array in `<pre>` tags, though it's likely a user contribution and not part of the core framework.

Here's the function basically:

```
function _pre($arr)
{
    echo '<pre>' . print_r($arr, true) . '</pre>';
}
```

Now it will output your array using this formatting...

```
Array
(
    [0] => hello
    [1] => ram
    [2] => shyam
)
```

...instead of this formatting:

```
Array ( [0] => hello [1] => ram [2] => shyam )
```

Comment: Can you give me any reference ?

Comment: The only reference to a public module for CI which uses `_pre` is part of the Toast unit testing module but it's a private method and doesn't accept an array as a parameter, so it's definitely not the OP's code.